# Why inert pair effect is seen in P- block elements only

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

why is inert pair effect specific to certain groups? Why heavier transition elements DO NOT show inert pair effect?

Comment: The inert pair effect is *not* limited to p-block elements. It does affect transition metals. However, the energy difference between d- and s-electrons is less than between p- and s-electrons, so the effect is less pronounced.